# What's the time complexity for downcasting an object?

Tags: java, c#, optimization, casting, time-complexity

I received a generic `Object` type instance from a RPC service that I want to cast to a `MyClass` type instance, what is the time complexity for this operation? Performance is critical to my application. (For languages like Java and C#)

Example: `Employee employee = (Employee) person;` or `PurchaseData purchaseData = (PurchaseData) genericData;`

Comment: casting is resolved in compile time, so doens't really matter on runtime

Comment: If it's a compile time action, then why there are run-time casting failures?

Comment: Because you say: "I *assume* x is an X" at compile time. At runtime, x could still be an Y. A cast is an **instruction** to the compiler telling the compiler: "I know better than you, that x here, I think it is an X, so please treat it that way".

Comment: OP has really shot themselves in the foot by conflating Java and C#. They are different languages with different run-time and compile-time behaviors. As a result, they're getting a muddy mess of intertwined responses. My advice is ask these kinds of questions about a single language. Just because 2 languages have "similar" syntax, does not mean they should be expected to behave the same.

Answer (score 4):

Casting is first of all a *compile* time activity.

At runtime, if at all, assume O(1). You see, all such information (like class structure) is *fixed* when code gets executed.

Given the comment: assuming that your Object was deserialized as instance of class X, then the JVM already *knows* that said object is actually of class X. The object exists in memory, and its exact class is just one lookup away!

Beyond that: assuming that your objects come in via a some sort of RPC call, and they are *deserialized* from some sort of transport representation into JVM objects ... do you really think that the time for *casting* matters? Calling a remote service might need milli seconds, even seconds. And you worry if casting such objects later on will takes 5 nanoseconds or 15 or 25?

The only situation that can cause a significant performance: when that cast goes wrong, and you run into a ClassCastException.

Comment: What if I received the generic Object type instance from a RPC service?

Comment: It's not about how long each cast takes, because it needs to be done inevitably. It's about how many times we do this cast and the design: cast once and pass the instances down or pass the generic ones down and cast at multiple places where they are needed(cast many times).

Comment: Downcasts are a symptom of a bad design anyway. And make no mistake: in 2018, you should try to design a system where you receive your objects already with the correct time. The JVM knows the exact type when deserializing, so make sure you define interfaces that return these types, instead of Object.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I am actually the consumer of the data and I am only designing the system to consume the data.

Comment: I can only repeat: if *casting* objects becomes the performance bottleneck in your system, then you don't have a performance problem. Again: alone the act of (de)serializing a **single** object can easily result in hundreds of thousands of CPU instructions. After it was deserialized, its type is know. And the inheritance tree is known too. All of that is static information, not going to change. You are seriously spending your time and energy on the **wrong** aspects of your system. A single method call that blocks without a need for half a second would make up for a gazillion of casts.

Comment: @wz366 As already said, casting is pretty fast. Optimizing it surely isn't something you should spend a minute thinking about. Pass down the cast instance if it makes the code clearer; pass the generic instance if that's clearer (unprobable but possible). If it's the same, then leave it as is; there's nothing to gain here.