# Time complexity of typecasting double to int in Java

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, big-o

```
double val = 500.00;
int val2 = (int) val;
```

What is the time complexity of typecasting in the previous example?

Is it `O(1)`?

Comment: Go ahead and write a test, that will indicate which way it goes.

Comment: The question is nonsensical.  The process of converting *one* `double` to type `int` has fixed input size, so it does not make sense to ask about how it scales with input size (which is what asymptotic complexity concerns).

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50975728/10115296

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey That question is similar or related. This one is not a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s constant time, O(1).

It couldn’t really be anything else since there’s a finite (although large) number of possible values. So even if larger values took longer (which I doubt, and which might depend on the CPU and other circumstances), there is an upper bound to the time it can take. By the definition of big-O this suffices for calling it O(1).

John Bollinger comments:

> It seems a stretch to interpret the magnitude of the input value as
> the problem size, as I guess this answer does. All bits of a Java
> double are significant to its value, so double values representing
> smaller-magnitude numbers do not present smaller conversion problems.

I agree 100 %. It was really there to indicate that the idea of specifying a time complexity for this operation at all is far-fetched. A more natural measure of the input would be the number of bits in it. Constant 64 bits. Which also gives O(1).

Comment: It seems a stretch to interpret the magnitude of the input value as the problem size, as I guess this answer does.  All bits of a Java `double` are significant to its value, so `double` values representing smaller-magnitude numbers do not present smaller conversion problems.